# NullPointerException when creating OBJECT ARRAYS and using them

Tags: java, arrays, object, nullpointerexception

I am new in java and I've got a problem while working with arrays of objects. My main program is like this:

```
package bicycledemo;

class BicycleDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Create two different 
        // Bicycle objects with an array
        Bicycle[] bike = new Bicycle[2];

        bike[0].cadence=50; //line 10, where the NullPointerException prompts out
        bike[0].gear=2;

        bike[1].cadence=10;
        bike[1].gear=3;

        System.out.println("gear: "+bike[0].gear+"\n"+"cadence: "+bike[0].cadence+"\n");
        System.out.println("gear: "+bike[1].gear+"\n"+"cadence: "+bike[1].cadence+"\n");


        System.out.println("\b");
    }
}
```

and the Bicycle class is this one:

```
package bicycledemo;

public class Bicycle {
    public Bicycle() {

    }

    public int cadence;
    public int gear;

}
```

When I run the program, the output error is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at bicycledemo.BicycleDemo.main(BicycleDemo.java:10)
Java Result: 1
```

I suppose that what happens is that the object bike is not correctly created, but I don't see why.

Thank you very much for your help! I am really desperate to resolve this!

Comment: @TedHopp: No, the code really *doesn't* look fine at all.

Answer (score 4):

This line:

```
Bicycle[] bike = new Bicycle[2];
```

creates an array. It has two elements, and both elements are initially null references. You haven't created any `Bicycle` objects. Then in the next statement:

```
bike[0].cadence=50;
```

... you're trying to dereference that null value. You need to initialize the elements of the array before you use them as objects:

```
// Set the first element of the array to refer to a newly created object
bike[0] = new Bicycle();
// Then this will be fine
bike[0].cadence = 50;
```

If you don't understand exactly what's going on here, it's *really* important that you study it more closely. Understanding the difference between references and objects (and understanding that variables and arrays only *ever* contain references or primitive values, *never* objects) is fundamental to Java. Until you "get" that, you'll run into all kinds of difficulties.

Note that you could also change your `Bicycle` class to include a constructor taking the cadence and gear as parameters:

```
public Bicycle(int cadence, int gear) {
    this.cadence = cadence;
    this.gear = gear;
}
```

Then you could change your initialization into:

```
bike[0] = new Bicycle(50, 2);
bike[1] = new Bicycle(10, 3);
```

Or even as part of the array creation:

```
Bicycle[] bike = {
    new Bicycle(50, 2),
    new Bicycle(10, 3)
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I was so confused because I was comparing with C++ and this doesn't happen, so I couldn't see the answer!

Answer (score 2):

you never initialized your array elements, Thus as your array element is an Object they get initialized to their **default value null**. thus when you try to invoke the element at an index it throw **NPE**.

```
    Bicycle[] bike = new Bicycle[2];// initializes the array with size 2
                                       but the elements hold default
                                        values(null in this case)
   bike[0] = new Bicycle();// initializing the array element at index 0
   bike[1] = new Bicycle();// initializing the array element at index 1
```

Of course the better design is also to have 2-args Bicycle constructor and initialize your attributes in it.or to have setter and getters for your attributes.

```
  public Bicycle(int cadence, int gear){
        this.cadence = cadence;
        this.gear = gear;
   }
```

Then,

```
        bike[0] = new Bicycle(2, 2);
        bike[1] = new Bicycle(3, 5);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I was so confused because I was comparing with C++ and this doesn't happen, so I couldn't see the answer!

Answer (score 2):

You need to populate your array first:

```
Bicycle[] bike = new Bicycle[2];
bike[0] = new Bicycle();
bike[1] = new Bicycle();
```

Otherwise, you create an array which just contains null elements.

Answer (score 2):

You have to set each index in the array to a new instance before you can start accessing its properties.

```
Bicycle[] bike = new Bicycle[2];

bike[0] = new Bicycle(); // add this

bike[0].cadence=50;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You created an array of objects and access them without initializing.

```
bike = [null, null] - your result
```